# netselect - how to get it installed on Mint?

Tags: apt

I have been using Linux already for a couple of years, and got used with it. Most of distro I used are: Centos, Ubuntu, Fedora, etc. Recently I decided to put in one of my machines Mint and I must admit to love it, specially for multi-media stuff.

One thing I couldn't figure out alone is about Netselect - an extremely useful tool indeed http://www.lowendguide.com/1/using-linux/useful-debian-command-netselect-apt . Why Mint doesn't include it as part of the package available to install from the Software Manager?

This program I installed it with no problems on Ubuntu, but on Mint, I didn't find a way out to put it up and running. I even looked around with google and no information about it. I also looked in the available softwares from the software management. But nothing there about netselect.

One thing I found was this link: https://packages.debian.org/stable/net/netselect . But the problem is, if you download and try to install it with `dpkg -i *.deb`, then the installation crashes complaining about dependencies, that if you try to solve, then will ask for another dependency, and that's goes on and on.

Is there some way to enable netselect to run on Mint?

Comment: Also, could you try to be more specific about the exact dependency errors?

Comment: Right. Now it worked. I just installed all dependencies https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/netselect-apt , then downloaded the deb file https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/netselect/download . Clicked on it and the package manager did the trick this time. Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and add an answer below then please!

Comment: Just added the answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed all [dependencies](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/netselect-apt), then downloaded the deb [file](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/netselect/download). Clicked on it and the package manager did the trick this time. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit: dead links